# How do you listen to hardware keyboard events in phonegap iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, keyboard-events

I created a Meteor app and want to port it to a native iOS app via Phonegap. I've successfully ported it but now I'm trying to listen to hardware keyboard events (to listen to an HID barcode scanner).

I'm using this snippet to catch "keypress" in a sample app. The sample app is working in http://marz.meteor.com/chat

```
#Coffeescript
Template.chat.rendered = ->
    $(window).on "keypress", (e) ->
        if not $("input.send_message").is(":focus")
            key_pressed = String.fromCharCode e.which
            console.log key_pressed
            current_value = $("input.send_message").val()
            $("input.send_message").val(current_value + key_pressed)

Template.chat.destroyed = ->
    $(window).off()
```

This doesn't work in iOS though, at least not through the simulator with the hardware keyboard enabled. What do I need to do to get it working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes but it's not exactly what I wanted. I'm going to learn swift and build a plugin for this issue as soon as I get some free time to do so. I ended up making a button that would focus on the input that was listening to the keyboard. In reality it all depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks, please write an answer/comment one you get to write this plugin :)

Comment: Did you manage to write a plugin to distinguish hardware and software keyboard? :P

Comment: Hey! I never got around to it and now I'm building on React Native instead >_<. For HID scanning I think having the user click a button that focuses on an offset element is an ok solution until a hardware keyboard event listener plug is released by the community though